# ordered: Then, activate the button .. or after, activate the button

Tags: java, android, select, android-music-player

> This is the work flow.
>
> When selecting the music, I want it
> to play it, and if I select it on another, it will reset and stop the
> clip that was playing, then it will move to the other and play it.
>
> > **The question: Simply these are three codes. I want to activate the**
> > **latter after the previous one is activated**.
>
> Note: I succeeded in adding the command to press the play button **But** If I delete the first code (reset&stop) that plays by simply selecting it on
> the list, **But** it never stops playing music and piles on top of each other nonstop

```
           sound.reset();
           sound.stop();
           btn_play.callOnClick();
```

> > The code part is complete

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            sound.reset();
            sound.stop();
           btn_play.callOnClick();


            sound = MediaPlayer.create(SoundActivity.this, listitems.get(i).sound);
            tvTitle.setText(listitems.get(i).getTitle());
            SoundTime();

        }
    });



    final boolean[] isPlay = {false};
    btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!sound.isPlaying()) {
                Thread updateSeekBar;
                updateSeekBar = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int SoundDuration = sound.getDuration();
                        int currentPostion = 0;
                        seekBar.setMax(SoundDuration);
                        while (currentPostion < SoundDuration) {
                            try {
                                sleep(100);
                                currentPostion = sound.getCurrentPosition();
                                seekBar.setProgress(currentPostion);

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                sound.start();
                updateSeekBar.start();
            }
```

Comment: does calling sound.stop() before you call sound.reset() help ?

Comment: Sorting order has been added in all its forms and I also tried adding (sound.start), but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: When I click on (btn_play) manually, there is no problem. The problem is when selecting and clicking

Comment: You might get better answers if you make clear what you are trying to do (context), and where it fails

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to those who tried to help me. I found a very simple solution
> after effort and effort:>

> I moved (btn_play.callOnClick) down like this

```
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            view.setSelected(true);
            sound.stop();
            sound.reset();


            
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(SoundActivity.this, listitems.get(i).sound);
            tvTitle.setText(listitems.get(i).getTitle());
            SoundTime();
            btn_play.callOnClick();

        }
    });
```

> Now it remains for me to auto-switch to the next music